# Flutter with firebase backend, using SDK or REST API?

Tags: firebase, rest, flutter

i am building some kind of uber like apps using flutter with firebase as the backend. I learn using flutter with firebase by using REST API from some tutorial i find on the internet. He decided to teach using REST API so that if you want to use other backend beside firebase than what he teach still viable.

But i wonder, whats the different? what is the benefits of using firebase SDK if you are going just using firebase after all?

and is it by using firebase SDK i can get offline sync features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The precise answer depends on which Firebase product(s) you're using (as there are 18 of them at this point of writing), your specific use-case, how you implement it, and personal preference. But I'll give some rough guidance. Given your mention of offline sync, I'm going to assume you use either the Realtime Database, or Cloud Firestore.

The Firebase SDKs contain a lot of code to handle offline storage, managing connectivity, managing read and write operations while the client is offline, and much more. If such behavior is important to you and you're using the REST API, you will have to write the code for the behavior yourself. Whether that is worth your time, only you can tell. I personally only use the REST API if I need to target a platform for which there's no Firebase SDK available.