# How to insert/delete an item by index in an "array" in Firebase's realtime database?

Tags: arrays, list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I have 3 vehicles in array, ordered by an index.

So my array looks like this:

```
// My array
const array = [
 { name: 'car', index: 1 }, 
 { name: 'aeroplane', index: 2 },
 { name: 'bus', index: 3 }
];


// How I push to the database
database.ref('/').push(array[0]);
database.ref('/').push(array[1]);
database.ref('/').push(array[2]);

// How my realtime db looks right after
{
  "-M9UBf4uJa9cy0_ZT4LF" : {
    "index" : 1,
    "name" : "car"
  },
  "-M9UBf50Jdyo4GmXO23l" : {
  "index" : 2,
  "name" : "aeroplane"
  },
  "-M9UBf526cmgjUw99dWw" : {
  "index" : 3,
  "name" : "bus"
  }
}
```

No problem so far.

However, I'm struggling when it comes to deleting or inserting vehicles in Firebase, because the indexes remain like they were. So for example, If I delete 'airplane' above with the following code:

```
// Delete second item
database.ref('/-M9UBf50Jdyo4GmXO23l').remove();
```

...I get an array like this:

[{name: 'car', index: 1}, {name: 'bus', index: 3}].

I need the bus's index to become '2' instead of remaining '3'. I realize there's no built-in way to achieve this using Firebase's API (and on purpose, since it would create problems in real time applications). However, I absolutely need the indexes to remain.

I thought about manually .update()-ing every index greater than the one I deleted but in cases where I have millions and millions of vehicles, wouldn't the performance be horrible?

Is there any way I could this with Firebase's realtime database or should I go with another database?

Comment: @GrahamD I edited my original post to include some code snippets. If there's anything else you'd like to see, let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're right, I'm not storing the array. I could expand on my use case but my real application is much more complex and quite huge, so I had to simplify it with a dummy use-case. Let's suppose I'm simply trying to show a list of vehicles on my website which have to be ordered (for example to show the results of a race). Vehicles can be removed from the list and have to be inserted in the middle (or in any index).

Comment: So for example I'd use car1, airplane2, bus3 etc?

Comment: You may be approaching this the wrong way. The order of data in Firebase 'doesn't matter' so the concept of 'inserting' a node in Firebase doesn't exist. You data is ordered according to how you want to get the data back via a query. It's unclear why you would need to 'insert' a vehicle when you had *millions and millions of vehicles* - if you can elaborate a bit on when you would need to 'insert' a vehicle and what the parameters are for the insertion, we can probably suggest a structure.

Comment: Alright but say I want to add a 2boat. How would I go about changing 2bus and 3airplane to become 3bus and 4airplane?

Comment: @Jay Each user logs in the website and starts with a list containing 0 vehicles. They add vehicles with a preference rating (1 best, 2 second best etc). There is no limit to the vehicles they can add.

Comment: @GrahamD Just a FYI, while the push key may be in order, the REST API Returns Unsorted Results: JSON interpreters do not enforce any ordering on the result set.

Comment: In these cases, vehicles are stored in one node and the ratings are stored in another with a reference to that vehicle. If a vehicle is added to the vehicles node and the user decides it's their #2 car. The result is it becomes #2 (in their list), and all of the cars from #2 to the end are 'pushed down' an index. With that structure, updating the rating of 10000 nodes of data happens almost instantly and with low overhead because it's only a few thousand bytes of data.

Comment: @jay I don't use REST API

Comment: @GrahamD The OP or others may so thought it would be good to know not to depend on order by natural keys in those use cases.

Comment: @jay the OP and others should therefore reference this SO post regarding when and when not to use REST API rather than the preferred Firebase SDK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57345466/flutter-with-firebase-backend-using-sdk-or-rest-api

Comment: @Jay thank you very much, I'll try implementing the dual node approach. I think your answer covers me practically.